# Latest NodeJS compatible with Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows-7

I am trying to install NodeJS for windows 7. I tried installing the most recent NodeJS but it is not compatible with Windows 7. I was wondering if anyone knows what is the latest version of NodeJS you can install on Windows 7? 
Thank you.

Comment: Support for Windows 7 ended on January 14, 2020..

Comment: I can't as its a work laptop :/

Comment: million dollar Questions is why would NodeJs declare incompatibility with windows 7 i mean whats so special or rocket science they using that they need windows 10 for it ? more like Microsoft pay check they got so that users move from win 7 to win 10

Comment: @user889030 The Windows API is versioned, so if you compile with a feature set introduced in Windows 8 or Windows 10, then it cannot run on Windows 7.

Comment: ERROR: Node.js v13.8.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=14.0.0 <15.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=15.0.0 <17.0.0 (Current Release)

This is the error. You just can download node version between 12.13.0 to 13.0.0
It worked for me

Comment: The question has been closed but it's a high value question for legacy Windows 7 users. Here is my finding for 2023.

The breaking change stops newer Nodejs running on Windows 7 is `os.hostname()`, which is widely used in node ecosystem.

The current confirmed inofficial working versions are Node `v14.17.6` and `v16.6.2`. None other versions higher work for Win7. (For the comment position, I'd not epxlain why, sorry)

Answer (score 183):

**Update: Oct 2021**, the latest versions working with below `"trick"` are:

- **Node v14.16.1** (or older but not below v14.5.0)
- **Node v15.8.0** (or older but not below v15.0.0)

> Because Node updated from `libuv v1.40` to `v1.41`,
> and with that, causing Win7 errors:
> `ws2_32.dll` does not have `GetHostNameW` function (or something alike).

---

### The workaround Method <sup>(for versions mentioned above)</sup>

The **v12.x branch** seems to continue supporting Win7 (tested 2021 with Node v12.22.7).

But I needed **14.x** version-branch and ended solving problem;
I just installed Node 14.15.0, like:

- Go to [Node-downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- Download the **Windows Binary (.zip)** (either 32/64 bit)
- Extract it in the directory where your node is installed and say yes to replace all files (remember that the zip comes with `npm`, which is in `node_modules/npm` directory; I didn't copy from the zip because I already updated npm before replacing the files)
- Create an Environment variable called: [`NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_skip_platform_check_value) and set it to `1`
- Ready to use Node in Windows 7 for now.

Comment: This works, I installed 15.5.1 on x86 Win7. This should be the accepted answer as this is the most helpful. Thanks tttony!

Comment: To be precise you need to do this command in your cmd : `set NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK 1` to setup your environement variable

Comment: Thank you very much, confirmed working on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Tested with node version 15.8.0 and npm v7.5.1. Cheers!

Comment: node-v14.17.6 is also runnable on x64 Win7

Comment: With this method, currently I am able to use v16.6.2

Comment: I can confirm that 16.6.2 is working (tried 16.13.1 before, without success). For this `node` version you would probably want to update `npm` to avoid warnings, for me only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955293/5177728) answer worked, just don't forget to also rename `npx`

Comment: @Sam Thanks this version worked on windows 7 x64 I should check more later. but i could upgrade npm to latest version now.

Comment: You might also want to delete the contents of the nodejs directory. The older undeleted files may cause issues.

Comment: I can confirm that this method is working for node version 16.15.0 on my pc (64bt). Thank you for sharing. Big help

Comment: I had to use cmd prompt as admin and use `setx NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK 1` which worked for v16.15.0 x64

Comment: Did some testing. v14.17.6 works but v14.18.0 does not.

Comment: This works. I installed node-v18.12.1-win-x86.zip from the downloads on a windows 7 32bit.

Comment: I had to remove the folders `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` as well as `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\npm` before copying the install files over from the zip. Else the npm did not work properly afterwards. After copying the files from the zip I ran `npm install npm@latest -g`.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas Which node version did you install?

Comment: @tttony Currently I am using node-v18.12.1-win-x64 but earlier versions had similar problems

Comment: To use `v14` branch and newer you must set `NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK=1`. From `v14` branch latest working is `v14.17.6` (newer fails due to missing WS2_32.dll). But newer branches again works! I can confirm that nowadays these latest `v16.20.2`, `v18.18.2` works and from `v20` branch works only until `v20.2.0` including (newer fails due to missing KERNEL32.dll).

Comment: `v16.6.2` works as well, but some node modules e.g. `jest` expect `14.15.0 || 16.10.0`, so `v14.17.6` is more compatible then the the v16.x. I spent almost half day to figure out if recent Nodejs versions still support Win7. But the answer is no, no longer possible, after `libuv` is upgraded to `v1.42` or higher.

Comment: @mikep recent Node versions works with condition. It will not fail, unless you or the any node dependencies call `os.hostname()`. For me, I use `pm2`, which will fail after attempting to check the hostname...

Answer (score 53):

Latest node.js version that (officially) supports Windows 7 is 13.6.0.
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.6.0/

Comment: To add some context, newer 13.6 versions might also work fine but 13.6 was the last one *tested*: Using EOL Windows versions is discouraged, we offer no guarantees that Node.js works correctly. The last Node.js versions tested on Windows 7/2008R2 are 10.18.1, 12.14.1 and 13.6.0. This does not block major Node.js versions up to 13 from running on EOL Windows as it's probably better to use a later version, even if untested (since there are no breaking changes). https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31954

Comment: 13.9.0 last version of node js which worked for me (win7x64) : https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.9.0/node-v13.9.0-x64.msi : 14+ versions are not installed on my win7.

Comment: I'm running Node.js v15.13.0 on Win7x32 with no problems at all.

Comment: Thank you @zeroG. Your comment solved my issue. However, in my window, if I run node command in cmd it says node not recognized. However, if I run cmd as administrator everything works fine.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that v13.14.0 is the last installer that works on Window 7

go here and select the package related to your version of windows 32 / 64 bits:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/

Answer (score 11):

I just install in Windows 7 x64 this version

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.14.0/

Comment: didn't work for me ... v13.6.0 is the last working as dziku86 mentions

Comment: @webMan Manually download the required, archived version from https://nodejs.org/dist/ , extract it and replace current version with the newer one.