# error could not determine Node.js install directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I have tried to install ionic by doing `npm install ionic`

`ionic start myapp blank` does not work and since then any npm commands tells me :

```
$ npm config
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dandonneau.m\devc\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Could not determine Node.js install directory
```

Comment: Uninstall the node.js and just reinstall it

Comment: Don't install npm as a local package dependency.

Comment: the terminal needs to be closed and reopened too

Comment: I had the same issue with nvm when installed the latest version of node. Solved the issue by running the command 
```nvm use xx.x.x```

Comment: I HATE Node.JS ... so many problems. Everything is problematic.... and yet... all those people using this ( sheet  )...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error because I was using a too new version of Node for my system.

- I have Windows 7.
- The last officially tested version of Node on Windows 7 is 13.6.0 [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615875). Although, you can also try to run newer versions such as 15.8.0 [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626035).
- The bug occurred when I tried to use Node version 17.1.0.

**Solution**

1. I solved the problem by downgrading the Node version to 15.8.0 (in my case via [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), you can just re-install).
2. You can also try upgrading your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to install Node over already installed NVM, you might need to delete that installed Node version and re-install NVM (that helped in my case I executed a PowerShell script that installed Node over my NVM)
here is the link to install the NVM for [Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.10/nvm-setup.exe).