# npm start throwing an error as 'cannot find module'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mern, npm-start

I have been trying to run **`npm run start`** command to start my react app but every time I run this command it is showing me below error.

```
$ npm run start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\string-width\index.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\wide-align\align.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\render-template.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\plumbing.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\index.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\lib\log.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\log-shim.js  
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)  
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\string-width\index.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)      
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',      
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\string-width\\index.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\wide-align\\align.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\render-template.js',  
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\plumbing.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\lib\\log.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nod-shim.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\exit-handler.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',      
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'   
  ]
}
Could not determine Node.js install directory
```

As error says `Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'` so I went to '*C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\emoji-regex'* to check is there any problem with *emoji-regex* npm module but when I clicked on that folder it showed an error as **file or folder is corrupted or unreadable**.

Now, I want my react app to run uninterruptedly but not able to do that, so can anyone plz help me in resolving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself says that you have added a dependency in `package.json` file, but it's not found in `node_module` folder. So, simply do `npm i` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: none npm command is working it is throwing same error

Comment: okay, so try by uninstall node.js from `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and then again install it, and also delete your node_modules folder and install it again after re-install node. it may help!

Comment: it is not getting uninstalled or reinstalled there also it is throwing error as 'The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2330.'

Answer (score 0):

Issue found to be same : [error could not determine Node.js install directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559611/error-could-not-determine-node-js-install-directory)
Try down grading node version, delete node-modules, check all the packages name available in package.json, finally do npm install.
Then npm run start should be working

Comment: tried installing and uninstalling of node.js but it didn't work,  thrown an error also I tried deleting node.js folder directely but that also didn't work as it could not get deleted.

Comment: did you reduce the version of node, check the version using node -v  and switch between versions using nvm

Answer (score 0):

Remove Node Modules and Package Lock:
navigate to your project directory and delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file. This will ensure that all previous dependencies are removed and a fresh installation can be started.

```
cd path/to/your/project
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
```

If the emoji-regex is in a global npm folder, it may be worth reinstalling npm. You can do this by running:

```
npm uninstall -g npm
npm install -g npm
```

If your project requires the emoji-regex package, make sure it's listed in your package.json file and run:

```
npm install
```

If the package isn't needed in your project but is required by npm itself, you may need to repair your Node.js installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your username folder, in C:... has a name with a forbidden character, for example, if your user name is 'R&D'... the path when npm runs will be C:\Users**R**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red... notice that the name is wrong, is just the "R", and it will not run, because the folder doesn't exist... it would be best if you create that path, and that username folder, and paste the content of the node-red folder. Node-red