# Using create-react-app with old node version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

is there any create-react-app version possible to install on node 13.6.0? I can't use actual node cuz of win7. With my actual node a lot of create-react-app dependencies shows me that they require newer or older version of node.

```
    Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'browserslist@4.17.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-utils@3.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.0.0 || ^12.0.0 || >= 14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'nanoid@3.1.25',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10 || ^12 || ^13.7 || ^14 || >=15.0.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'postcss@8.3.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10 || ^12 || >=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'browserslist@4.14.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'pretty-format@27.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-diff@27.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'pretty-format@27.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/types@27.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'diff-sequences@27.0.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-get-type@27.0.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/types@27.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v13.6.0', npm: '7.21.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

After npm start I have

```
Error: No valid exports main found for '..app\node_modules\colorette'
```

Comment: This might help you to install NODE on windows7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, react on my way.

Comment: Super! Keep it up mate