# Node version needs upgrading?? but its higher than what its recommending?

Tags: node.js, npm

Im trying to run

```
npm run serve
```

on a certain project.

and I get

> vue-notus@1.1.0 serve F:\WEB_DEV\Github\vue-notus-main
> vue-cli-service serve

```
ERROR  You are using Node v13.14.0, but vue-cli-service requires 
Node ^12.0.0
Please upgrade your Node version.
```

Which is confusing.  Its asking me to upgrade but I clearly have a higher version that ^12.0??

Or does it want me to downgrade??

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [current version](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/b0e7bf07d6d7e086985475df713b593cb42ef878/packages/%40vue/cli-service/package.json#L124) of `@vue/cli-service` requires

```
"node": "^12.0.0 || >= 14.0.0"
```

but the error message doesn't show that for some reason.

Upgrade to Node >= 14; 13.x is not a LTS release, which is likely why it's not explicitly supported.

Node 16.x is the current LTS release.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Upgraded to 16 and it worked.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm on windows 7 which only supports Node v13. Is there any possible way to use Vue CLI?

Comment: @castbound Windows 7 hasn't been supported for two years. Nevertheless see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626035/51685

Answer (score 2):

The carat at the start of a version in `package.json` indicates that you must have a *major* version that is **equal** to the version specified.

According to [the `semver` documentation](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions):

> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero element in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

That is to say, your Node version of `13.14.0` is outside of the range `12.x.x` (which is required by your version of `vue-cli-service`).

You will either need to *downgrade* Node, or *upgrade* `vue-cli-service`.

Comment: The explanation is correct, but the solution is not correct in the case of `@vue/cli-service`; see my answer...