# is there any way to install the latest version of nodjs to windows 7?

Tags: reactjs

the best suitable node js version(node-v13.14.0-x64) for windows 7 had many errors and can't start react app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3tit.png)
so I need the latest version to be very good for windows 7

Comment: There is no error there. Besides, The last version of Node no longer runs in Windows 7.

Comment: but i can't npm start react js with this older version

Comment: Why not? What problem do you have then?

Comment: @Alejandro
could you please see the photo and tell me your opinion https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_U2Kz7MYehMD_w1TdAP0OOsbZ8CFP3yI/view?usp=sharing In spite of I searched and found some one wrote this code "scripts": {
"test": "echo\"Error: no test specified\"&& exit 1",
"start": "node App.js"  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_N8TvTtdEDBLpIcfb-LEzDuz3EZ4Yts/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they are just warning that you may ignore. But if you still want to update node js on windows 7 then you can just go through this solution asking the same question: [NodeJS for windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7)

Comment: was refused to work on win7

Comment: thanks but didn't help https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_U2Kz7MYehMD_w1TdAP0OOsbZ8CFP3yI/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_N8TvTtdEDBLpIcfb-LEzDuz3EZ4Yts/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ibrahim, can you please show your packege.json files' screenshot where the "scripts" property is there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xvsq0Yjq0GvnW6SxyJGptyQBgNK1nXz0/view?usp=sharing thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: @Ibrahim, try adding script object in your package.json file like this:

`"scripts": {"start": "react-scripts start"}`

Comment: Dear @Aashrut Vaghani sorry for your time because finally, I found that the first constructor to install react to write " npm install create-react-app" but when I change to another constructor, I found that it was " npm install -g create-react-app" and it worked successfully. thanks a lot for your time GOD bless you and your efforts

Comment: Great @Ibrahim, I am glad to know that you found the solution to your problem. And also, thank you for your best wishes! It was a pleasure to help you.