# Problems using react npx

Tags: reactjs, npx

So I have an error when I try to run the npx create-react-app app-name command on my console, both in vscode and in terminal.
The console always returns:

You are running Node 12.22.8.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.
Please update your version of Node.

I tried to install a more up-to-date version of node but it's not possible because I use windows 7 and from version 14 onwards it only supports windows 8. I tried to reinstall but I wasn't successful either. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this??

Comment: Check this on how to use `create-react-app` without `npx` https://gist.github.com/gaearon/4064d3c23a77c74a3614c498a8bb1c5f

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

npx create-react-app app-name is used with node version 14 or higher. For less version first you have to install create-react-app  with following commands

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app@3.4.1
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version 3.1.1
```

It is better to upgrade window and then node version.