# update npm on windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7, windows-7-x64

After I use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7?answertab=active#tab-top) I successfully updated current `node` version to v16.6.2 on win7x64, but now `npm -v` throws errors:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

is there way to fix it? And I have not enough reputation ask about it that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), configured system environment variables and update my node version to latest by command `nvm install latest`