# How to support ES6 syntax in Nodejs 12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using the current version 12.0 of NodeJS but i am having trouble with ES6 syntax. Node doesn't understanding the syntax of ES6 like `optional chaining`, `export` & `import` but i need to use it in my project.

In short, how can I use ES6 syntax in NodeJS v12.0 without using TypeScript compiler? Any babel support it?

Comment: Why not upgrade to a more recent version of NodeJS that supports those features?

Comment: @Andy The newer versions of NodeJS don't support the operating system I'm using (Windows 7)

Comment: @ALittleGirl https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626035/362536

Comment: @Brad This "trick" still not works for me. I got the error information: `The Application is only supported on windows 8.1, windows server 2012 R2, or Higher` after install it

Comment: @ALittleGirl You added `NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK` to your environment?  There are folks there that said it worked as of a couple weeks ago.

Comment: It's worth noting that Node 12 is well past the point of getting security updates and I would recommend using a newer supported version.