# Is there any way to install latest reactJs app on windos7

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React. Although I am studying the react, I am not too clear about the concept react and react-native.

When trying to install react native app I am getting an error:
Command:  npx expo-cli init reactapp

ERROR: Node.js v13.14.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

- > =12.13.0 <15.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
- > =16.0.0 <17.0.0 (Active LTS)

When tried to install the latest version I am not able to get that on windows7 can anyone let me know if there's any way to install the latest React version on my OS? Please don't suggest changing the OS. I cant do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Windows7, it is related to your version of NodeJS (the back-end server-side environment that works with ReactJS). First you install Node, then you install React -- Node is required for React development.

Upgrade your version of NodeJS and all should work.

For your other question:
ReactJS is the programming library (kind of like a framework) for writing React apps. ReactNative (poorly named) is a specialized version of React that is specifically for writing mobile (phone) applications.

You can review this link to see how to install a specific version of NodeJS:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-the-previous-version-of-node-js-and-npm/

Here is information re the latest versions of Node that works with Windows7:

[NodeJS for windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got the difference in React and React Native.  But my main problem is that I cant install the latest version of node on the windows 7, I already tried that when I got the error for "create-react-app"( the command for creating and installing the react app)

Comment: See update to my answer - added SO link to identify the latest versions of Node that work with Windows7 ( [NodeJS for windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/nodejs-for-windows-7) ).  Then, follow the instructions in the geeksforgeeks article for how to install a specific version of Node.

Comment: I have tried that already, and I think I have the latest version 13.14.0 which can be installed on windows 7... So my main question is, is there any other trick or some solution that would be used to install the higher than 13.14 version on windows 7? I already know that on the latest Windows OS I can install them but I can't switch to a higher version of windows.

Comment: Not that I am aware. You might try asking at the [NodeJS repo on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/discussions) - that's the best I can suggest, and you'll be speaking directly to the horse (i.e. hearing it *straight from the horse's mouth*, so to speak)

Comment: Ok bro thanks for the help so far, I would try asking, and hope I would get some better solution

Comment: I have installed windows 10 on the virtual machine(VMware) and installed it there. Though your answer didn't solve the issue it helped me to understand the basics.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version by `node -v` and if it is older than 12.13.0, try upgrading it to the latest LTS version. hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: My Node verion is v13.14.0