# uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS using Vue CLI

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am installing a project in vuejs but me display this error does any idea how to solve it.

```
D:\> vue create crud-app
node:os:68
        throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
        ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
     at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node -ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
     at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-ipc\dao\client.js:11:19)
```

[image: Terminal output when using vue create crud-app]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Suraj Rao thanks for your answer but I can ;t copy message error in my cmd. Thanks in adavance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543856/4826457

Comment: @Suraj Rao   D:\> vue create crud-app
node:os:68
      throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
      ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname retur
ned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
    at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node
-ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
    at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i
pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\dao\client.js:11:19)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @Suraj Rao First of all I followed this linke in you tube ans followed all instruction.  After that me dispaly this error.

Comment: Can you try to run the command in your user directory in C drive and check if it works?

Comment: @Suraj Rao For which command do you have mean?

Comment: `vue create crud-app`

Comment: yes but if I run command of the vue or  this command above me display  this error:  D:\> vue create crud-app
node:os:68
      throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
      ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname retur
ned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
    at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node
-ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
    at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i
pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: @Mery are you using Windows 7? If so, your Node.js version might be too new. Look [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1410#issuecomment-1124005921).

Comment: I said in **C:\>**

Comment: what version of node?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by how the window looks in your screenshot, you might be using Windows 7.

If so, the last version of Node.js with official Windows 7 support is either v13.6.0, v13.14.0 or v14 (conflicting sources). You're using v16.14.0, which is too new.

There seems to be a workaround to install newer versions, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626035

I cannot comment on how well it works, or if it works at all.