# npm run dev not working with vite laravel 9

Tags: npm, vite, laravel-9

```
users-iMac-2:backend NEHAL$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

file:///Users/user/Desktop/backend/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:122:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
users-iMac-2:backend NEHAL$
```

Comment: did run `npm i` after initiating the project ?

Comment: According to [laravel 9 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#installing-node) for working vite in laravel You must ensure that Node.js (16+) and NPM are installed. For developers that are using windows 7 I suggest to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212754/latest-nodejs-compatible-with-windows-7)

Answer (score 20):

Same problem. Updated node to v16.16.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem; the installed version of NodeJS on your OS is incompatible with `vite`; mine was `v12.22.9`; upgrade yours.

If you're using a debian-based OS, run the following.

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: @X 47 48 - IR did you test with node v12.22.9 and it works? I have node ```v13.14.0``` in my windows 7 and get the same error. Do you have any solution for me? Because as I know newer versions of **Node** do not work with windows 7.

Comment: Try using `Docker` (It's independent of the OS); I have dockerized everything myself. It's so easy to catch up with new updates.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I was using docker.

Comment: I use node version manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), much easier to switch back and forth to the version you need.

Comment: Great method! Seems like a newer version has been released. I think people try this method should also check the latest version. 
(Do Ctrl+F "setup_" in the following official page to know the latest version)

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using lower  [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) version, you can install multi Nodejs version and change between them In my case I install

```
v14.0.0
v16.0.0
v18.0.0
```

In your case you should use version `v16.0.0` OR `v18.0.0` run terminal as **`admin`** and run this command to use a specific version:

```
nvm use v18.0.0
```

And rerun command again

```
npm run dev
```

It works without any problem

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, you try installing **Node.js** like v16/v18. you got rid of the error message on Ubuntu.

```
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent/dists/main/InRelease: Key is , see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jammy Rele
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Used these commands to solve the ERROR :

`sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:certbot/certbot`

After that, the following commands do not generate any errors:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install Nodejs from the **Official [github repo](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions)**

and make **Vuejs** build from `npx vite build`
for **Npm** build from `npm run build`.

Answer (score 1):

Use yarn instead
First remove package-lock.json and node_modules folder.

```
rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json
```

Then run:

```
yarn install
```

Run build command:

```
yarn build # or yarn dev
```