# How to get around "Unexpected reserved word" when installing Laravel Jetstream?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm

I am following the instructions at https://jetstream.laravel.com/installation.html for installing Laravel Jetstream.

I run `artisan jetstream:install` and choose to install with Livewire support, API support, email verification and PHPUnit support.

I then run `npm install` per the instructions, and everything seems to work.

Finally, I run `npm run build` per the instructions. Uh oh! I now get the following message:

```
> build
> vite build

file:///home/mrmayor/Documents/coding-projects/super-great-project/backend/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your node version and OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on `Vite` due to **NodeJS Version Incompatibility**. Try upgrading your `NodeJS` to `v16` or **Latest**.

For More Details: [npm run dev not working with vite laravel 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048645/npm-run-dev-not-working-with-vite-laravel-9)