# How can i run my first React App on windows7

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have windows7 and when I  download Node.js, it said me : it can't work on windows 7 , finally I download Node.js  v14 , and it work , but when I tried install packages for App , it cannot work and waned me to update to v16 and v16 doesn't work on windows7, any one knows anything about this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [updating node.js in windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822612/updating-node-js-in-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: Which packages are you trying to install? Which commands did you used? How have you installed node?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.